# Get multiple extensions in a for loop for transforming jpg,JPG and jpeg files

Tags: bash, shell

I want to convert all jpgs (independent from lower or upper case or jpeg extension) in my current directory to a 95% optimized one. However I do not get the files correctly in my for loop with JPG,jpg and jpeg files :/

```
#!/bin/bash
PIC=$(ls "$PWD"/*.{jpg,jpeg,JPG})
for i in $PIC
  do
   echo $i
   # convert $i -quality 95 ${i%.*}_resaved.jpg
done
```

Comment: Are you certain there are files of this type in `$PWD`? That `ls` command works for me when I try it in a folder with similar files.

Comment: Yes I'm sure. But I got very strange results with paths which have spaces and directories which do not have .jpeg files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223817/608639), [for loop for multiple extension and do something with each file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12259331/608639), [Loop over multiple file extensions from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49103942/608639), [for loop in bash go though files with two specific extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34382072/608639), etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try:

```
find -iname "*.jpg" -o -iname "*.jpeg" | while read f; do
  echo "$f"
  convert "$f" -quality 95 "${f%.*}_resaved.jpg"
done
```