# for loop in bash go though files with two specific extensions

Tags: regex, bash

I want the following loop to go through m4a files AND webm files. At the moment I use two diffrent loops, the other one just replaces all the m4a from this loop. Also the files that ffmpeg outputs should remove a m4a extension if it was a m4a file, and a webm extension if it was a webm file. And replace that with mp3. (As it does here with m4a). I have no Idea how to do it, I think it has something to do with regex expressions, but I have no idea how really use them nor have I ever found a good tutorial/documentation, so if you have one, please link it aswell.

```
for i in *.m4a ; do
        echo "Converting file $converted / $numfiles : $i"
        ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel fatal -i "$i" "./mp3/${i/.m4a}.mp3"
        mv "$i" ./done
        converted=$((converted + 1))
done
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223817/608639), [for loop for multiple extension and do something with each file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12259331/608639), [Loop over multiple file extensions from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49103942/608639), etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for i in *.m4a *.webm; do
  echo "Converting file $converted / $numfiles : $i"
  ffmpeg -hide_banner -loglevel fatal -i "$i" "./mp3/${i%.*}.mp3"
  mv "$i" ./done
  converted=$((converted + 1))
done
```

- You can use `for` with *multiple* patterns (globs), as demonstrated here: `*.m4a *.webm` will expand to a single list of tokens that `for` iterates over.

  - You may want to add `shopt -s nullglob` before the loop so that it isn't entered with the *unexpanded* patterns in the event that there are no matching files.
- `${i%.*}.mp3` uses [parameter expansion](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/pe) - specifically, `%` for shortest-suffix removal - to strip any existing extension from the filename, and then appends `.mp3`.

Note that the techniques above use *patterns*, not regular expressions. While distantly related, there are fundamental differences; patterns are simpler, but much more limited; see [pattern matching](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Pattern-Matching.html).

<sup>P.S.: You can simplify `converted=$((converted + 1))` to `(( ++converted ))`.</sup>

Comment: That works. But I'm pretty sure it would break if the filename contains mode then one `.` here `${i%.*}` . Is there a way that it won't break, or am I wrong?

Comment: @usbpc102: No, it won't break, because `%` is used for _shortest_ suffix matching (it _would_ break if you used `%%` for _longest_ suffix matching instead). Try it yourself: `i='one.two.m4a'; echo "${i%.*}"`