# Loop over multiple file extensions from bash script

Tags: bash

I need a bash script for use in the Linux terminal which should go something like:

```
#!/bin/bash 

for textgrid_file in ./*.TextGrid and for wav_file in ./*.wav
do 
   praat --run pitch.praat "$textgrid_file" "$wav_file" >> output.txt
done
```

I.e. I need to iterate through pairs of files with extensions `.textgrid` and `.wav` because in my Praat script `pitch.praat` I have two arguments to pass. How can I implement it via bash scripting?

Comment: Iterate over one or the other and swap the extension.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223817/608639), [for loop for multiple extension and do something with each file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12259331/608639), etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an array support to iterate over first glob pattern and use 2nd file from array:

```
waves=(*.wav)

k=0
for textgrid_file in *.TextGrid; do
    praat --run pitch.praat "$textgrid_file" "${waves[k++]}" >> output.txt
done
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you right, both filename share the same basename.

```
#!/bin/bash 
for textgrid_file in ./*.TextGrid 
do 
    name=$(basename $textgrid_file .TextGrid)
    wfile="$name.wav"
    praat --run pitch.praat "$textgrid_file" "$wfile" >> output.txt
done
```

Extract the common basename with basename.