# Bash script: Looping through multiple file extensions in folder, ignoring file extensions that don't exist

Tags: linux, bash

I have a directory of pictures, which can contain jpeg, jpg, and png files. I want to loop through them in a bash script. Its possible for the directory not to contain any png files, or jpeg files, or jpg files. If a file extension doesn't exist, my script gives an error. How to ignore these?

```
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,png} ; do
 echo $file
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223817/608639), [for loop for multiple extension and do something with each file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12259331/608639), [Loop over multiple file extensions from bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49103942/608639), [for loop in bash go though files with two specific extensions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34382072/608639), etc.

Answer (score 3):

You can check if the file exists:

```
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,png}; do
  [ -e "$file" ] || continue
  # Here "$file" exists
done
```

You can also use [`shopt -s nullglob`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/glob#nullglob) which will avoid expanding to non existing files:

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,png}; do
  # Here "$file" exists
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can set the `nullglob` option, which causes a wildcard that has no matches to expand to an empty list instead of expanding to itself.

```
shopt -s nullglob
for file in *.{jpg,jpeg,png}; do
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use extended patterns.

```
shopt -s extglob nullglob
for file in *.@(jpg|jpeg|png); do
    echo "$file"
done
```

`*.{jpg,jpeg,png}` expands first to `*.jpg *.jpeg *.png`; each of the three patterns then undergoes path name expansion. `*.@(jpg|jpeg|png)`, on the other hand, is a *single* pattern that undergoes path name expansion.