# for loop for variable multiple extension

Tags: bash, shell, glob

How to change [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12259331/for-loop-for-multiple-extension-and-do-something-with-each-file):

```
for file in "$arg"/*.{jpg,jpeg,png} ; do
    echo "$file" > z.txt
done
```

To:

```
for file in "$arg1"/*.{$arg2} ; do
    echo "$file" > z.txt
done
```

Since I will get the extension list as a single (comma separated) argument. The above attempt doesn't work.

Comment: by the look of it I think this will work

Comment: @Inder It won't. Brace expansion is done **before** variable expansion.

Comment: BTW, do you want `z.txt` to have at most only one name? If you want it to have *all* resulting names, put the `> z.txt` after the `done`, so you're opening and truncating the file only once, at the very start of the loop, and leaving it open until the loop ends.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223817/608639), [for loop for multiple extension and do something with each file](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12259331/608639), etc.

Comment: @jww OMG, how I hate SO, I regret every time I have to interact with this.... PLEASE **READ**, THIS IS **NOT** A DUPLICATE OF THOSE. I even referred to the dubbed "duplicate" in this damn question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `extglob` to pass pipe delimited extension list like this:

```
arg2='jpg|jpeg|png'
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for file in "$arg"/*.@($arg2); do
    echo "$file"
done > z.txt
```

Or if you want to keep comma separated argument then use `bash` substitution to replace comma with pipe as this script:

```
arg2='jpg,jpeg,png'
shopt -s extglob nullglob

for file in "$arg"/*.@(${arg2//,/|}); do
    echo "$file"
done > z.txt
```

Comment: Hmm. The original code would emit a literal output of `*.png` if no files matching that glob exist, whereas this will only emit the glob itself as output if no files matching **any** of the extensions given exist. Unless the OP ran `shopt -s nullglob` first, of course.

Comment: I was just adding `nullglob` while you commented this important point

Comment: Thanks. I'm accepting this one because I can still change my argument syntax and replace commas for pipes, and it's shorter.

Comment: If you still want to have comma separated argument then change `for file in "$arg"/*.@($arg2);` with `for file in "$arg"/*.@(${arg2//,/|});`

Answer (score 6):

Use an array to store the extensions, then iterate over the array.

```
IFS=, read -a extensions <<< "$arg2"
for ext in "${extensions[@]}"; do
  for file in "$arg"/*."$ext"; do
      echo "$file" > z.txt
  done
done
```

Comment: Hmm. It's a fair question whether there's a case for leaving out the `-r` argument to `read` here; in favor of running without the `-r`, it allows extensions with commas to be used; against, it removes literal backslashes without any explicitly specified behavior that makes that desired.

Comment: Very gracious of you to assume I didn't just leave out the `-r` out of laziness :) (which I did).

Comment: The chance that anyone would want to have either comma or backslash in the extension is so close to zero that it has to be printed with exponential notation.

Comment: @Barmar, ...I've got more outputs from `locate '*/*.*,*'` than you might expect. Granted, none of these look like files for which anyone would be searching by extension.

Comment: Thanks, great answer, I've accepted the other one because: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51506835/for-loop-for-variable-multiple-extension#comment89983273_51507018

Comment: I like the other one as well.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Right. Files like them exist (I vaguely recall a version-control system with `,version#` naming scheme), but the chance that you'd want to search for them in this type of script is negligible.

Comment: *nod*, RCS and CVS used `,v` extensions, IIRC. (I actually have a long rant about that format, being former maintainer of a conversion tool from CVS repositories to the GNU Arch revision control system -- updates being prepended to the file, and UNIX not natively supporting prepend operations without a rewrite, it was easy to have old history become silently unavailable during updates, and to have this never be noticed until backups had aged out... so when someone was running my tool was often the first time they learned that a file suddenly no longer had pre-2004 history available).