# Looping through files of specified extensions in bash

Tags: macos, bash, loops

I am trying to loop through files of a list of specified extensions with a bash script. I tried the solution given at [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6223817/matching-files-with-various-extensions-using-for-loop) but it does not work as expected. The solution given was:

```
for file in "${arg}"/*.{txt,h,py}; do
```

Here is my version of it:

```
for f in "${arg}"/*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu}
    do
        echo "$f"
    done
```

When I run this in a directory with an `epub` file in it, I get:

```
/*.epub
/*.mobi
/*.chm
/*.rtf
/*.lit
/*.djvu
```

So I tried changing the `for` statement:

```
for f in "${arg}"*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu}
```

Then I got:

```
089281098X.epub
*.mobi
*.chm
*.rtf
*.lit
*.djvu
```

I also get the same result with:

```
for f in *.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu}
```

So it seems that the `"${arg}"` argument is unnecessary.

Although either of these statements finds files of the specified extensions and can pass them to a program, I get read errors from the unresolved `*.` filenames.

I am running this on `OS X Mountain Lion`. I was aware that the default bash shell was outdated so I upgraded it from `3.2.48` to `4.2.45` using `homebrew` to see if this was the problem. That didn't help so I am wondering why I am getting these unexpected results. Is the given solution wrong or is the `OS X` bash shell somehow different from the `*NIX` version? Is there perhaps an alternate way to accomplish the same thing that might work better in the `OS X` bash shell?

Comment: Hi. Could you explain in more detail what you're trying to do? Since the code is broken, it's hard to use *that* as a description of what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This may be a BASH 4.2ism. It does not work in my BASH which is still 3.2. However, if you `shopt -s extglob`, you can use `*(...)` instead:

```
shopt -s extglob
for file in *.*(epub|mobi|chm|rtf|lit|djvu)
do
    ...
done
```

---

> @David W.: shopt -s extglob for f in *.*(epub|mobi|chm|rtf|lit|djvu) results in: 089281098X.epub @kojiro: arg=. shopt -s nullglob for f in "${arg}"/*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu} results in: ./089281098X.epub shopt -s nullglob for f in "${arg}"*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu} results in: 089281098X.epub So all of these variations work but I don't understand why. Can either of you explain what is going on with each variation and what ${arg} is doing? I would really like to understand this so I can increase my knowledge. Thanks for the help.

In mine:

```
for f in *.*(epub|mobi|chm|rtf|lit|djvu)
```

I didn't include `${arg}` which expands to the value of `$arg`. The `*(...)` matches the pattern found in the parentheses which is one of any of the series of extensions. Thus, it matches `*.epub`.

Kojiro's:

```
arg=. 
shopt -s nullglob 
for f in "${arg}"/*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu}
```

Is including `$arg` and the slash in his matching. Thus, koriro's start with `./` because that's what they are asking for.

It's like the difference between:

```
echo *
```

and

```
echo ./*
```

By the way, you could do this with the other expressions too:

```
echo *.*(epub|mobi|chm|rtf|lit|djvu)
```

The shell is doing all of the expansion for you. It's really has nothing to do with the `for` statement itself.

Comment: +1 Ah yes, the lovely `extglob`. I had forgotten it had this expression.

Comment: @David W.: Thanks for the explanantion. BTW `echo *.*(epub|mobi|chm|rtf|lit|djvu)` gives an error: `-bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`. I don't know why.

Comment: You have `shopt -s extglob` set? For some reason, Bash doesn't do extended blobbing automatically.

Answer (score 0):

A glob has to expand to an existing, found name, or it is left alone with the asterisk intact. If you have an empty directory, `*.foo` will expand to `*.foo`. (Unless you use the `nullglob` Bash extension.)

The problem with your code is that you start with an arg, `$arg`, which is apparently empty or undefined. So your glob, `${arg}/*.epub` expands to `/*.epub` because there are no files ending in ".epub" in the root directory. It's never looking in the current directory. For it to do that, you'd need to set `arg=.` first.

In your second example, the `${arg}*.epub` does expand because `$arg` is empty, but the other files don't exist, so they continue not to expand as globs. As I hinted at before, one easy workaround would be to activate `nullglob` with `shopt -s nullglob`. This is bash-specific, but will cause `*.foo` to expand to an empty string if there is no matching file. For a strict POSIX solution, you would have to filter out unexpanded globs using `[ -f "$f" ]`. (Then again, if you wanted POSIX, you couldn't use brace expansion either.)

Comment: @David W.: `shopt -s extglob`  
`for f in *.*(epub|mobi|chm|rtf|lit|djvu)`
results in:
`089281098X.epub`
@kojiro:
`arg=.`
`shopt -s nullglob`
`for f in "${arg}"/*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu}`
results in:
`./089281098X.epub`

`shopt -s nullglob`
`for f in "${arg}"*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu}`
results in:
`089281098X.epub`
So all of these variations work but I don't understand why. Can either of you explain what is going on with each variation and what `${arg}` is doing? I would really like to understand this so I can increase my knowledge.
Thanks for the help.

Comment: See the appending on my original answer.

Answer (score 0):

To summarize, the best solutions are to use (most intuitive and elegant):

```
shopt -s extglob
for f in *.*(epub|mobi|chm|rtf|lit|djvu)
```

or, in keeping with the original solution given in the referenced thread (which was wrong as stated):

```
shopt -s nullglob
for f in "${arg}"*.{epub,mobi,chm,rtf,lit,djvu}
```

Answer (score -1):

This should do it:

```
for file in $(find ./ -name '*.epub' -o -name '*.mobi' -o -name '*.chm' -o -name '*.rtf' -o -name '*.lit' -o -name '*.djvu'); do
  echo $file
done
```

Comment: -1 Parsing the output of `find` is almost as [bad as parsing `ls`](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs). It will break if any of the found files have whitespace in their names. Plus, if `find` is the right answer, then just do `find ./ -name '*.epub' -name …` and let find do the printing.

Comment: @kojiro 1. Are you kidding me? The only solution offered in that article is to use a glob. Not exactly the most flexible solution, particularly if you need to work on subdirectories. 2. OP has a for loop for "no reason" go complain at them. I'm operating under the assumption that the for loop is necessary for whatever they *actually* want to accomplish.

Comment: I stand by what I said – looping over a wordsplit command substitution is rarely a good idea. 1. A glob is extremely flexible, especially with extensions like nullglob, extglob and globstar, but even without them it's not clear OP wanted to recurse. 2. Again, if `find` is the right answer, the entire answer can be expressed with `find`. If `find … -print` isn't right, `find … -exec` is. Barring that, `find … -print0 | xargs -0 …`.