# How do I loop over multiple wildcards simultaneously in bash?

Tags: bash, shell, for-loop, wildcard

In bash, I've written a function that loops over files in a directory with multiple extensions using wildcards, and copies only these specific files if they exist. A snippet of the code looks like this:

```
set -e

pushd ../../../../$3/code/project/common/ > /dev/null
mkdir -p ../$2
shopt -s nullglob

for file in *.gyp; do   cp $file ../$2/; done
for file in *.gypi; do  cp $file ../$2/; done
for file in *.sh; do    cp $file ../$2/; done
for file in *.patch; do cp $file ../$2/; done

popd > /dev/null
```

I'd prefer instead to write one `for file in x` statement, so that I don't have to copy and paste this line for each extension I want to copy.

How can I rewrite the four `for` statements as one `for` statement? I would like to keep the `*.ext` wildcard format somewhere in there if possible.

Comment: See: [Matching files with various extensions using for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6223817/3776858)

Comment: [Shellcheck](https://www.shellcheck.net/) identifies several instances of missing quotes in the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should just be able to do

```
for file in *.gyp *.gypi *.sh *.patch; do   cp $file ../$2/; done
```

Comment: Well I feel silly… I don't think I would have ever thought of that, or that this would work. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: Based off of your response and Cyrus (from above), I've rewritten it as this, which is a bit more compact: `for file in *.{gyp,gypi,sh,patch}; do cp $file ../$2/; done`, and that's what I'll be going with. Thanks again!

Comment: This does not work if there are no matches, e.g. if there are no .sh files the value for $file will be '*.sh'

Answer (score 4):

[Brace Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Brace-Expansion) and a single `cp` command:

```
cp -t ../"$2" *.{gyp,gypi,sh,patch}
```

Always quote your variables, unless you know exactly what side-effects you want.

Comment: Imagine a user passed a directory name (as $2) that contains a space.